# How to send C2D message feedback response from IoT device in Python

Tags: python, azure, iot, azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-sdk

I have a python script running on an IoT device which receives messages from Azure IoT hub and does stuff. I want to get the feedback process working but am missing some understanding.

How do I send the feedback response from the device? Is it simply sending a cloud-to-device message using device_client.send_message formatted somehow with the message_id? Or is there some other send-feedback method that I'm unaware of? I dont see anything related to feedback responses [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-iot-device/azure.iot.device.iothubdeviceclient?view=azure-python#azure-iot-device-iothubdeviceclient-send-method-response).

I am using a Function App (written in js) to send the C2D message and it has a function that looks like it just logs the response on the console:

```
function printResultFor(op) {
    return function printResult(err, res) {
      if (err) console.log(op + " error: " + err.toString());
      if (res) console.log(op + " status: " + res.constructor.name);
    };
  }
```

When the feedback is sent from the device I assume it will be caught here. Do I then need to send this back to the IoT Hub somehow in order to utilize the retry functionality?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The C2D mechanism is one-way, the device doesn't send any response. If you want the device to send a response to the request, you should use a direct method instead. For more information, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-c2d-guidance.

To ensure once only delivery of C2D messages, IoT Hub uses a per device queue - to understand how this queue works, see, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-messages-c2d

According to the readme files in the C, C#, and Java device SDKs: "Receive cloud-to-device messages and read associated custom and system properties from IoT Hub, with the option to complete/reject/abandon C2D messages. *IoT Hub supports the option to complete/reject/abandon C2D messages over HTTPS and AMQP only at the moment*." The Python SDK currently [completes all C2D messages automatically - it's not possible to reject or abandon C2D messages](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-python/pull/1038).

Comment: In the second link you shared it states that "When a device thread completes the processing of a message, it notifies the IoT hub by completing the message." and that the device can also reject or abandon the message. What I'm asking is how to perform these actions from the device application.

Comment: The samples for the other language SDKs show how to complete, reject, or abandon a C2D message, but not the Python samples. Let me see what I can find out.

Comment: See my updated answer above.

Comment: Thanks @Dominic. That's a bummer it's not available for the Python SDK, seems like a pretty significant shortfall. Hopefully it's implemented soon.